# VBA Problem with the Div / 0 replacement loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have two loops that replace the result of Div / 0 with an empty cell, the problem is that the first loop works and the second one doesn't, there is no error, but only one table has a result

```
Dim MyRange As Range
With wbMe.Sheets("page3").Range("B30:D44")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Set MyRange = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
            MyRange.ClearContents
         End If
With wbMe.Sheets("page3").Range("B76:K89")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Set MyRange = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
            MyRange.ClearContents
        End If
```

Comment: Aren't the errors in cells having a formula? If so, please use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)`. In the code you show us, no ending `End With` can be seen. Probably, a typo...

Comment: The problem is, unless in the first table it just deletes where is Div / 0 and in the second, Div / 0 is the result of the formula. I don't know how to change it . And i have end With on end of macro

Comment: How are we supposed to know what "works" and "doesn't work" mean? FaneDuru has probably described your issue though.

Comment: But I've just suggested what is to be changed... `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` instead of `SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlErrors)`.

Comment: FaneDuru its working ! Thanks a lot :)